# scala: fix the value of a param using curry

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I have the following function

```
scala> def f1 = (prefix: String) => prefix + ".field"
f1: String => java.lang.String
```

And I'd like to define another function from f1, that fixed the value of prefix to p1, like this

```
def f2: () => String = () => f1("p1")
```

or more shortly

```
def f2 = () => f1("p1")
```

I think that the same could be achieved using Function.curried or f.curried and partialy applied functions, but I still couldn't do it...

--

Having a look a [this article](http://sandrasi-sw.blogspot.com.ar/2012/03/understanding-scalas-partially-applied.html) I found a more verbose way of defining it. I guess the above syntax is just suger for this longer form...

```
scala> object f2 extends Function0[String] {
     | override def apply = f1("p1")
     | }
defined module f2

scala> f2
res37: f2.type = <function0>

scala> f2()
res38: java.lang.String = p1.field
```

Comment: You know that using `def`s you are actually defining methods, right? It only happens that those methods return functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only "curry" functions with more than one argument. At least with the methods that Scala provides by default. With two parameters it works like this:

```
val f2 = (prefix: String, foo:String) => prefix + ".field"
val f1 = f2.curried("p1")
```

If you want to do the same with `Function1`, you can "pimp" the class to add a new method:

```
implicit def addCurry[A,B](f:Function[A,B]) = new Function1WithCurried(f)
class Function1WithCurried[-A,+B](f:Function1[A,B]) {
  def curried:Function1[A,Function0[B]] = (x:A) => { () => f(x) }
}

def f1 = (prefix: String) => prefix + ".field"
val f0 = f1.curried
val f2 = f1.curried("p1")
```

Comment: Yes, I was suspecting that, so the only way to achieve it is manually defining a new function, like I did with f2

Comment: Thanks a lot for extending your answer. I don't understand where do you fix the prefix value in f0, it seems like your f0 is not the same as my f2

Comment: @opensas: f0 is just a function that takes a prefix and retuns a Function0. f2 is the function with the prefix "fixed". Just added that to the answer.

Comment: All right, that's exactly what I was looking for (correct answer). I wonder this is not included in scala, it seems useful to me

Answer (score 1):

Extending @Kim Stebel's answer bit further. You can do this:

```
scala> val f2 = (prefix: String, foo:String) => prefix + ".field"
f2: (String, String) => java.lang.String = <function2>

scala> val f1 = f2("p1",_:String)
f1: String => java.lang.String = <function1>
```

And to make it clear, what we are doing here it not currying, it's 'partial application'.

Answer (score 0):

If what you're looking for is currying, you could do it even more verbose like this:

```
scala> def f1(f: String => String)(s: String) = f(s)
f1: (f: String => String)(s: String)String

scala> def f2 = () => f1(p => p + ".field")("p1")
f2: () => String

scala> f2()
res4: String = p1.field
```